# Re-substituting solution to differential equation yields a contradiction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computer-algebra-systems

I have found a solution to the differential equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x^2 +t\sqrt{t^2 + x^2}}{tx}$$ where $t, x > 0$

to be:

$$x = t\ln{t} + ct$$

I calculated this by using the fact that the given differential equation can be written in the form:
$$M(x, y)dx + N(x, y)dy = 0$$

and the fact that both co-efficient functions M(x, y) and N(x, y) are homogeneous functions of the same degree, that is:

$$M(tx, ty) = t^\alpha M(x, y)$$

and

$$N(tx, ty) = t^\alpha N(x, y)$$

To check whether my solution is correct, I substituted my solution back into the differential equation to yield 0 = 1, that is, a contradiction. The only two possible reasons I have to this is either:

- My solution is indeed incorrect; or
- Re-substituting  my solution back into the differential equation
  and simplifying encountered an error in the process

I have also tried a few Computer Algebra Systems (CAS), including MuPad, to check this solution is correct by either:

- Symbolically finding the solution to the differential equation; or
- Substituting my solution to the differential equation

Interestingly, the former case couldn't find a solution and the latter case couldn't simplify the LHS and RHS.

Naturally, the fact that the checking process found a contradiction means the solution must be wrong, but I've sense checked it so many times I cant find anything erroneous.

My suspicion is that the condition t, x > 0 must have caused me to make a wrong step somewhere.

**My question is, is my solution incorrect or is my checking process incorrect?**

Comment: Maybe you can show more steps as [*WA*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27+%3D+%28x%5E2+%2B+t+sqrt%28t%5E2+%2B+x%5E2%29%29%2F%28+t+x%29) shows something different (which may be okay).

Comment: Now that is very interesting. Because I actually *did* get the WA solution in my third last step. My solution is in fact a simplification of the WA solution. Do you see what I did? I let c^2 - 1 be equal to C because its still a constant. That then allowed me to simplify the solution even more.

Comment: I get $$-{\frac {\sqrt {{t}^{2}+ \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}}}{t}}
+\ln  \left( t \right) -{C_1}=0
$$

Comment: Showing the full steps of your solution would go a long way in helping others spot errors, if indeed this was caused by some error.

Answer (score 1):

The equation being

$$x' = \frac{x^2 +t\sqrt{t^2 + x^2}}{tx}$$ first let $x=t y$ to make
$$t y'=\frac{\sqrt{y^2+1}}{y}$$ which is already separable if you write it as
$$\frac t {t'}=\frac{\sqrt{y^2+1}}{y}\implies \frac  {t'}t =\frac y{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$$
Integrate both sides
$$\log(t)+c=\sqrt{y^2+1}\implies y=\sqrt{(\log (t)+c-1) (\log (t)+c+1)}$$ and then
$$x=t\sqrt{(\log (t)+c-1) (\log (t)+c+1)}$$ which is a bit more complex than
$$x = t\log{t} + ct$$